# JSF 2, ajax input field behaves differently in firefox 10 and ie9

Tags: ajax, firefox, jsf-2, internet-explorer-9

When cursor is in input "test" and user press enter-key in a simplified form like

```
<h:form>
 <h:inputText id="test" value="#{myModel.someValue}" >
  <f:ajax event="blur" execute="@this" listener="#{myBean.calculateStuff}" render="myText"/>
</h:inputText>

<h:outputText id="myText" value="#{myModel.myText}"  />

<h:commandButton value="send" action="#{myBean.calculatedNextPage} ">

</h:form>
```

firefox invokes 1 submit, ie invokes submit and partial-request.

Is this behaviour ok? From application side it is nuisance, because there is prevention/detection for multiple request on client/server side.

We don't know the page outcome beforehand if some field's validation/conversion has failed and we might not get updated "myText" rendered on both browsers. Enter-key check to prevent from submitting is not desirable and "blur" is good in normal cases. Any suggestions how to get both browser working the same way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behaviour is indeed not desired. But MSIE as whole browser at its own also not. That's what you have to deal with as being a web developer. Firefox/Chrome/Safari/etc correctly skip the blur event when the submit event has occurred.

If your sole purpose is to convert/validate `someValue`, then you should be doing that inside a normal converter and/or validator, not inside an ajax listener method.

```
<h:inputText id="test" value="#{myModel.someValue}">
    <f:converter converterId="someValueConverter" />
    <f:validator validatorId="someValueValidator" />
    <f:ajax event="blur" execute="@this" listener="#{myBean.calculateStuff}" render="myText"/>
</h:inputText>
```

This way you can just safely ignore "unnecessary" ajax requests.

But if you really have a hard head in, you can *in your particular example* always add an `onsubmit` handler to skip the `onblur`.

```
<h:form id="form" onsubmit="document.getElementById('form:test').onblur=null">
```

Comment: Idea is to show calculated value on "myText" (h:outputText). It is calculated at invoke application phase from myModel.someValue field.Thank you from your reply!.